# Comment posts record

Tags: support, comments

Is there a way to see one's comments in the same fashion as questions and answers are visible in one's profile ?

If not, is there any way to make that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can see your history of comments. Go to your user profile, then click on Activity on the top, All actions on the left, and Comments on the top-right.

[image: Shababnik's user page, with Activity, All actions, and Comments selected and circled]

Comment: Ah splendid ! Much obliged.